# Customise oath2 token request to accept extra data

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, jersey-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am using jersey and spring-oauth2 with spring security. My app is working fine with end points "/oauth/token".

I want to change the endpoints to accept more data. The requirement is, I want to send more details to the token API (i.e. the device details OS, phone/tablet/web etc.). So, I want to override the endpoint and if authentication is successful, I want to store that extra information in database.

I could not find anything related to changing the API in such a way.
Can someone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a solution by writing a wrapper controller and assigning default tokenEndpoint bean

```
@FrameworkEndpoint
public class LoginContrller{

private static Logger logger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginContrller.class);
private WebResponseExceptionTranslator providerExceptionHandler = new DefaultWebResponseExceptionTranslator();

@Autowired
private UserManager userManager;

@Autowired
TokenEndpoint tokenEndPoint;

@RequestMapping(value = "/user/login", method=RequestMethod.POST,consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ResponseEntity<OAuth2AccessToken>  postAccessToken(Principal principal, @RequestParam
Map<String, String> parameters,@RequestBody(required=false) LoginModel loginModel) throws HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException {
    ResponseEntity<OAuth2AccessToken> response = tokenEndPoint.postAccessToken(principal, parameters);
    if(!isRefreshTokenRequest(parameters)){
        if(loginModel!=null){
            loginModel.setUsername(parameters.get("username"));
            try {
                userManager.loginUser(loginModel);
            } catch (UserNotFoundException e) {
                logger.warn("Exception in custom login {} ",e);
            }
        }
    }
    return response;
}

private boolean isRefreshTokenRequest(Map<String, String> parameters) {
    return "refresh_token".equals(parameters.get("grant_type")) && parameters.get("refresh_token") != null;
}

private boolean isAuthCodeRequest(Map<String, String> parameters) {
    return "authorization_code".equals(parameters.get("grant_type")) && parameters.get("code") != null;
}

@ExceptionHandler(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class)
public void handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException e) throws Exception {
    logger.info("Handling error: " + e.getClass().getSimpleName() + ", " + e.getMessage());
    throw e;
}

@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ResponseEntity<OAuth2Exception> handleException(Exception e) throws Exception {
    logger.info("Handling error: " + e.getClass().getSimpleName() + ", " + e.getMessage());
    return getExceptionTranslator().translate(e);
}

@ExceptionHandler(ClientRegistrationException.class)
public ResponseEntity<OAuth2Exception> handleClientRegistrationException(Exception e) throws Exception {
    logger.info("Handling error: " + e.getClass().getSimpleName() + ", " + e.getMessage());
    return getExceptionTranslator().translate(new BadClientCredentialsException());
}

@ExceptionHandler(OAuth2Exception.class)
public ResponseEntity<OAuth2Exception> handleException(OAuth2Exception e) throws Exception {
    logger.info("Handling error: " + e.getClass().getSimpleName() + ", " + e.getMessage());
    return getExceptionTranslator().translate(e);
}

private WebResponseExceptionTranslator getExceptionTranslator() {
    return providerExceptionHandler;
}

}
```

Change in web.xml : just replace the URL with new one

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/user/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And finally create bean with logincontroller class and change the  URL in spring-security.xml.

Change the oauth token url and url of clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter as mentioned below.

```
 <sec:http pattern="/user/login" create-session="stateless" authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager" use-expressions="true" >

    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/user/login" access="isFullyAuthenticated()"/>
    <sec:csrf disabled="true"/>
    <sec:anonymous enabled="false" />
    <sec:http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <sec:custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
</sec:http>
<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <constructor-arg value="/user/login"></constructor-arg>
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
      <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/user/login" />
</bean>
<bean class="com.oauth2.provider.endpoint.LoginContrller" />
```

Comment: what about using java config annotation ?

Comment: Who is: UserManager userManager;