# Spring-Security-OAuth2 - how to add fields to access token request?

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

I have a Spring Boot application, that is using Spring Security with OAuth 2.0.  Currently, it is operating against an Authentication Server based on Spring Example code.  However, running our own Auth Server has always been a short-term target to facilitate development, not a long-term goal.  We have been using the authorization_code grant type and would like to continue using that, irrespective of the Auth Server implementation.

I am attempting to make changes to use OAuth 2.0 Endpoints in Azure Active Directory, to behave as our Authentication Server.  So far, I have a successful call to the /authorize endpoint.  But the call to get the /token fails with an invalid request error.  I can see the requests going out.

It appears that parameters that Azure states as mandatory are not being populated in the POST request.  Looking at the [Azure doco](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/active-directory/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code), it expects the client_id to be defined in the body of the message posted to the endpoint, and that is not added, by default, by Spring.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for how I can add fields to the Form Map that is used when constructing the Access Token request?  I can see where the AccessTokenRequest object is being setup in OAuth2ClientConfiguration....

```
@Bean
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
protected AccessTokenRequest accessTokenRequest(@Value("#{request.parameterMap}")
Map<String, String[]> parameters, @Value("#{request.getAttribute('currentUri')}")
String currentUri) {
    DefaultAccessTokenRequest request = new DefaultAccessTokenRequest(parameters);
    request.setCurrentUri(currentUri);
    return request;
}
```

Should I be trying to define the map in a request.parameterMap spring property?  If so, I'm not too sure how that works.

Or should I be using one of the interfaces defined in the AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter class?

I have the information to include when sending the AccessTokenRequest, I just don't know the best way to configure Spring to include it?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customise oath2 token request to accept extra data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31154557/608639)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found this out.  I needed to change the client authentication scheme.  Simply adding the following to my application properties added the client_id to the form....

security.oauth2.client.clientAuthenticationScheme=form

If you're using yaml, then yaml-ize it.  Thank you Spring!